# Parsing a webpage using php

Tags: php

Im looking for a simple way to scrape any webpage for the presence of certain keywords. I have a list of words such as {Apple, Banana, Pear, Pineapple} and I have a list of links. I need to search each page for the presence of my list of words and return which ones are present on each link. For example for a link:

http://www.xyz.com

I should search that page and return a vector of binary variables 0 1 1 0, where each respective binary variable corresponds to the presence or absence of each corresponding search key in the list. I am having trouble finding a way to search a webpage since i am new to php. what is the best way to scrape a webpage to get back only relevant text on the page (ie. no html tags or css or javascript metadata etc)? I have tried curl and get_file_contents but they returned pretty ugly representations of the webpage. Can anyone please provide a snippet that returns the text on a page so i can search that returned text?

Thanks in advance!

One of the main examples of curl not working is for the page https://plus.google.com/107630561301274451844/about?gl=us&hl=en

I am trying to find the keyword IL on it and it returns non-relavent text for me to search within.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using something pre-built

This will do what you're looking for: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/